# London Embankment cycle routes - are e-bikes allowed?

Tags: electric-bike, london

I went along these routes the other day for the first time since the pandemic.

Specifically I'm talking about the route from Blackfriars to the West, i.e. to Westminster.

I was annoyed by a number of people riding ebikes, seemingly quite powerful ones. A quick glimpse online seems to suggest that some ebikes are allowed on cycle ways. No doubt policing the prohibition of the more powerful ones would be quite hard work: no registration plate, and they can get away VERY fast!

But does anyone know what the rules are and who or what actually has responsibility for enforcing whatever rules there may be?

Answer (score 3):

According to https://www.gov.uk/electric-bike-rules the rules for eBikes (electrically assisted pedal cycle, EAPC) in the UK are very similar to other European countries:

> An EAPC must have pedals that can be used to propel it.
>
> […]
>
> Its electric motor:
>
> • must have a maximum power output of 250 watts
>
> • should not be able to propel the bike when it’s travelling more than 15.5mph
>
> Where you can ride
>
> If a bike meets the EAPC requirements it’s classed as a normal pedal bike.
> This means you can ride it on cycle paths and anywhere else pedal bikes are allowed.

So if they went faster than 15.5mph (25km/h) they were either using pure muscle power or the bikes were modified and therefore illegal. Of course even when riding muscle powered you mustn’t ride at dangerous speeds or endanger others.

Comment: The ones I saw yesterday were undoubtedly going at over that speed, at a guess I would say around 20-25 mph.  Without any pedalling.

Comment: The rules aren't really enforced

Answer (score 2):

There are two varieties of E-bikes: slow (25 km/h that is less than a speed of a fit cyclist, may be more restrictions) and fast (more like a small motorcycle). Simplest way to tell apart, a motorcycle like E bikes must carry number plates. Slow variety is mostly permitted where bicycles are permitted in general, but the fast variety not.

Comment: The problem is that with many eBikes the 25km/h limit can easily be removed. It’s also easy to import powerful and unlimited components.

Comment: This is obviously illegal. Police should sit and measure speeds.